# How to activate next tab and their content using tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am creating a jquery tabs using ul and li. i want to create a function using onblur when user press a tab key it will move to next tab. i want to when user in the last text box of tab 1 when it will press the tab key then it will move to next tab and active their content. I am creating tab using jquery not jquery ui. i am not using Tab index for this. i want to write a function onblur event.

Note:

```
 <ul class='tabs'>
                <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div id='tab1'>
                <ul class= "set2"> 
                    <li>  test 1<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test1" /></li>
                    <li>  test 2<asp:TextBox runat="server" onBlur(); ID="test2" /></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div id='tab3'>
                <ul class= "set2"> 
                    <li>  test 3<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test3" /></li>
                    <li>  test 4<asp:TextBox runat="server"  onBlur(); ID="test4" /></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div id='tab3'>
                <ul class= "set"> 
                    <li>  test 5<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test5" /></li>
                    <li>  test 6<asp:TextBox runat="server"  onBlur(); ID="test6" /></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("You are running jQuery version: " + $.fn.jquery);


    $('ul.tabs').each(function () {
        // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
        // which tab is active and it's associated content
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');


        // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
        // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.

        if ($('hdnCurrentTabSelection.ClientID').val() == "") {
            $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val(location.hash)
        }

        $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val() + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));
        window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().split('#')[0] + $active.attr('href');

        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        // Bind the click event handler
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
            // Make the old tab inactive.
            $active.removeClass('active');
            //window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().replace($active.attr('href'), '');
            $content.hide();

            // Update the variables with the new link and content
            $active = $(this);
            $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val($active.attr("href"))
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
            window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().split('#')[0] + $active.attr('href');

            // Make the tab active.
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show();

            // Prevent the anchor's default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

[This is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raji627/4n5fL/9/)

Comment: How abt creating a fiddle...!

Comment: Check out [jQuery EasyTabs](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/) maybe that will help you out instead of inventing the wheel again.

Comment: @RoySchoep in jQuery easy tab no event for tabs key

Comment: You can click on a tab programmatically `$('#tab1').click()` and open the contents of that tab. Is that what you want?

Comment: i am not doing an event on tabs. when user un last input type it will call the function that will activate the next tab and there content. plz read the problem clearly

Answer (score 0):

I am just posting the basic example

**jsfiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/tsANm/1/**

**html:**

```
      <ul class='tabs'>
            <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id='tab1' class="tabclass">
            <ul class= "set2"> 
                <li>test 1<input type="text" id="test1" tabindex="1"></li>
                <li>test 2<input type="text" id="test2" tabindex="2"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='tab2' class="tabclass">
            <ul class= "set2"> 
                <li>test 3<input type="text" id="test3" tabindex="3"></li>
                <li>test 4<input type="text" id="test4" tabindex="4"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='tab3' class="tabclass">
            <ul class= "set2"> 
                <li>test 5<input type="text" id="test5" tabindex="5"></li>
                <li>test 6<input type="text" id="test6" tabindex="6"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**css:**

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
html {
    padding:15px 15px 0;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
p, h3 {
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
div {
    padding:10px;
    width:600px;
    background:#fff;
}
.tabs li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}
.tabs a {
    padding:5px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#666;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.tabs a.active {
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
function reset() {
    $(".tabclass").hide();
    $("#tab1").show();
    $("#test1").focus();
    $("ul.tabs li a:first").addClass("active");
}
$(function() {
    reset();    
    $("ul.tabs li a").on("click", function() {
        i=0;
        $(".tabclass").hide();
        $("ul.tabs li a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    });

    var i = 0;
    var j = $(".tabclass").length;
    $("ul.set2 li input[type=text]").on("blur", function() {
        var inputFields = $(this).parents(".set2").find("input[type=text]").length;
        i++;
        if (i === inputFields) {
            var tabNum = parseInt($(this).parents(".tabclass").attr("id").toString().substring(3,4));
            $(".tabclass").hide();
            $("ul.tabs li a").removeClass("active");
            $("a[href=#" + $(this).parents(".tabclass").next().attr("id") + "]").addClass("active");
            $(this).parents(".tabclass").next().show();            
            $(this).parents(".tabclass").next().find("input[type=text]:first").focus();            
            i = 0;                       
            if (j === tabNum) {
                reset();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply @susheel but it is not according to my problem. i want to when user in the last text box of tab 1 when it will press the tab key then it will move to next tab and active their content.in your solution there is no text boxes onw more thing in your code first tabs content is not active.

Comment: you didnt mention that clear in your question. please add these lines  to your question. i will be back with your requuired answer

Comment: thanks for reply but in my question, i want to write on onblur function of text box.plz under stand it.here i am not pasted my all code. i want to create a functionality on every last textbox.in future if text boxes in increase this code will not work.

Comment: pls do not put  tabindes.bcz in my code it is already give by some dynamic method. i want to write using only onblur method

Comment: if you remove tab index also it will work but you manually need to focus on input field in next tab.@user3149053

Comment: thanks for reply u told "you manually need to focus on input field in next tab" that is the i am trying from many times. can u available for chat? i want to discus the problem. i am also from hyd